# IIS URL Rewrite Not Working As Expected

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, sitefinity

I had this URL Rewrite like this:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Item Detail">
        <match url="^item/(?!(action/edit)|(action/preview))([_0-9a-z-()@$!']+)"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="item?item={R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

In hope to rewrite `item/something-dash-something` as `item?item=something-dash-something`. The rewrite rule does working as expected in doing the initial intention. Unfortunately the `(?!(action/edit)|(action/preview))` part did not exclude preview mode (`action/preview`) as expected despite Page Designer mode (`action/edit`) works properly. I am not sure what am i missing since testing the regex in [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/jcwKy7/1) shows that it works as expected. I also have tested it in RegexStrom also.

**EDIT**: 
Tested Victor's suggestion, to no avail. The Rewrite still fires for `action/preview`. The next silly item is (inspired by Victor answer), tested this rule and it does not work as expected also:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Item Detail">
        <match url="^item/([_0-9a-z-()@$!']+)"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(action/edit)" negate="true"/>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(action/preview)" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="item?item={R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Anyone had better idea..? Did i miss something?

**EDIT 2**: This one still not working also..

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Item Detail" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^item/(?!action/)([_0-9a-z-()@$!']+)"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="item?item={R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

i have no idea why `preview` seems to be ignored and passed the url rewrite.

**EDIT 3**:
Stupid me, one of the widget still assumes there will always query string. Case closed, the `stopProcessing="true"` is a good addition nonetheless..

Comment: This begs the question - why do you need that rule? isn't it better to have it /item/something rather than /item?item=something?

do you have any issues with the mvc routing?

Comment: for SEO purpose, need to translate `item/some-item-name` to `item?item=some-item-name`, legacy system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude preview and edit URLs with condition:

```
<rule name="Item Detail">
    <match url="^item/([_0-9a-z-()@$!']+)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(action/edit)|(action/preview)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="item?item={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I tested rule twice and rule is not rewriting when you have `action/edit` or `action/preview` in your url

Comment: it simply the rule fires.. still creates `item?item=`, weird indeed, seems my IIS is at fault.

Comment: May be do you have another rule, which is affecting? Can you try to put this rule at the top?

Comment: hmm, should not be the case, this rule already on the top most in the `web.config` rewrite rule collection.

Comment: Also can you please add stopProcessing like that  `<rule name="login rewrite" stopProcessing="true">` into your rule. Just to be sure that other rules are no affecting

Comment: added and still not working as expected.. weirdly, it seems to ignore url rewrite if had 'preview' on the url..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157970/discussion-between-victor-leontyev-and-bagus-tesa).